# Black screen after boot with Nvida drivers and bios screen corruption

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, xorg, nouveau

(PS: Cross posting at [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324197))

I've a old Rock x770 laptop (clevo M57RU) with nvidia GTX7950go graphics card, intel core2duo 2.4Ghz.

I've been running xubuntu 14:04 with the Nvidia 304 drivers since it came out, with no issues. Recently I I suddenly started seeing vertical rows of white dots on the BIOS screen and it would boot to a black screen. Going to tty terminal and looking at the X logs I see Xserver is crashing with "(EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting" .

I can get it to work using nomodeset in grub boot line, and using the Nouveau drivers, but only at a low res 1280 x 1024 (native res is 1920x1200), as soon as I switch to nvidia drivers from the Additional Drivers app its back to black screen, even after a fresh install. If I take nomodeset off with Nouveau drivers it gets to logon screen, but heavily corrupted and freezes.

Have tried lots of suggestions for un-install and re-install of various drivers and X packages Tried xrandr to switch modes, but that has no effect when in the low res/nouveau mode, just a brief flicker and message `Configure crtc 0 failed`.

Tried fresh re-installs of 14.04, and 16.04 to no avail, always limited to nomodeset and low res with Nouveau drivers. Its no longer used for 3d or games so would be happy with Nouveau drivers if could get the full res.

From what I’ve researched one likely possibility is that the bios screen corruption indicates that the graphics card has gone faulty and is only able to run in basic low res VGA mode.

So, any-one able to suggest anything else to try before I look to replace the graphics card? (Its a MXM module so can be done, if i can find one). I've seen suggestions of baking the graphics card in the oven! which I might try first when I’ve nothing left to lose- http://www.overclockers.com/forums/s...N-TRICK-WORKED.

Xorg log with nvidia drivers showing crash:

```
[    18.101] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[    18.101] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    18.101] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    18.102] Current Operating System: Linux dtrock01 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 17 20:50:15 UTC 2016 x86_64
[    18.102] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-85-generic root=UUID=1b56f9c8-966f-4d22-a9f1-3ea226b89524 ro nomodeset quiet splash
[    18.102] Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
[    18.102] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    18.102] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[    18.102]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    18.102] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    18.102] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue May  3 20:37:54 2016
[    18.168] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    18.193] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    18.193] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    18.193] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    18.193] (**) |   |-->Monitor ""
[    18.194] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    18.194] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    18.194] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    18.194] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    18.194] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    18.194]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    18.194] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    18.194]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    18.194] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    18.194]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    18.194] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    18.194]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    18.194] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    18.194]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    18.194] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    18.194] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    18.194] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    18.194] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f6916e37d40
[    18.194] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    18.194]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    18.194]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[    18.194]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[    18.194]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[    18.194] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    18.196] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:0297:1558:0573 rev 161, Mem @ 0xcd000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xce000000/16777216, I/O @ 0x00002000/128
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension Present
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[    18.196] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[    18.196] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[    18.196] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    18.196] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[    18.196] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    18.254] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    18.867] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    18.867]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    18.867]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    18.867] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.131  Sun Nov  8 22:03:20 PST 2015
[    18.868] Loading extension GLX
[    18.868] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    18.868] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    18.868] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 2
[    18.868] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 3
[    18.868] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 4
[    18.868] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 5
[    18.868] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 6
[    18.868] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    18.868] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    18.868] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    18.942] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    18.942]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    18.942]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.963] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    18.973] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nouveau
[    18.973] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    18.973] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    18.973] (EE) Failed to load module "nouveau" (module does not exist, 0)
[    18.973] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    18.973] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    18.973] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.973]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[    18.973]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.973]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    18.973] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    18.973] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    18.973] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.973]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[    18.973]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.973]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    18.973] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    18.974] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    18.974] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.974]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
[    18.974]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.974]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    18.974] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    18.974] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    18.974] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 2
[    18.974] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 3
[    18.974] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 4
[    18.974] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 5
[    18.974] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 6
[    18.974] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    18.974] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    18.974] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    18.974] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    18.974]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    18.974]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.974] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    18.974] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    18.974] (II) Failed to load module "nvidia" (already loaded, 32617)
[    18.974] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    18.974] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nouveau
[    18.974] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    18.974] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    18.974] (EE) Failed to load module "nouveau" (module does not exist, 0)
[    18.974] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    18.974] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    18.974] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.974]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[    18.974]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.974]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    18.975] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    18.975] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    18.975] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[    18.975] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    18.975] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    18.975] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.975]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[    18.975]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.975]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    18.975] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    18.975] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    18.975] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[    18.975] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    18.975] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    18.975] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.975]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
[    18.975]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.975]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    18.975] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    18.975] (II) Unloading vesa
[    18.975] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
[    18.975] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  304.131  Sun Nov  8 21:45:02 PST 2015
[    18.975] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    18.976] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    18.976] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    18.976] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    18.976] (++) using VT number 7

[    18.978] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    18.978] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    18.978] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    18.978] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.978]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[    18.978]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    18.978] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    18.978] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    18.978] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    18.992] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.992]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[    18.992]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    18.992] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    18.992] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    18.992] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    19.008] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    19.009] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    19.009] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    19.009] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    19.009] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    19.009] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    19.009]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
[    19.009]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    19.009] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    19.009] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    19.009] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    19.009] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    19.009] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    19.009] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    19.009] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    19.009] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    19.009] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    19.914] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (LGD (DFP-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D Vision
[    19.914] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     stereo.
[    19.943] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce Go 7950 GTX (G71) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    19.943] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 524288 kBytes
[    19.943] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 05.71.22.51.09
[    19.943] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    19.943] (--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
[    19.943] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GeForce Go 7950 GTX at PCI:1:0:0
[    19.943] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
[    19.943] (--) NVIDIA(0):     TV-0
[    19.943] (--) NVIDIA(0):     LGD (DFP-0) (connected)
[    19.943] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[    19.943] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    19.943] (--) NVIDIA(0): TV-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    19.943] (--) NVIDIA(0): TV encoder: Unknown
[    19.943] (--) NVIDIA(0): LGD (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    19.943] (--) NVIDIA(0): LGD (DFP-0): Internal Dual Link LVDS
[    19.943] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    19.943] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: Internal Single Link TMDS
[    19.943] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    19.943] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device LGD (DFP-0) (Using EDID frequencies has been
[    19.943] (**) NVIDIA(0):     enabled on all display devices.)
[    19.943] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    19.943] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    19.943] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[    19.943] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    19.943] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    19.943] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[    19.943] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1920 x 1200
[    19.944] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to support custom viewPortOut 1920 x 1080 +0 +60
[    19.960] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to support custom viewPortOut 1600 x 1200 +160 +0
[    19.960] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to support custom viewPortOut 1500 x 1200 +210 +0
[    19.961] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to support custom viewPortOut 1920 x 1080 +0 +60
[    19.961] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to support custom viewPortOut 1600 x 1200 +160 +0
[    19.961] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to support custom viewPortOut 1600 x 1200 +160 +0
[    19.962] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to support custom viewPortOut 1600 x 1200 +160 +0
[    19.962] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (131, 132); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[    19.962] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[    19.962] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    19.962] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    19.962] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    19.962] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    19.962] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    19.962] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    19.962] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    19.962] (II) Unloading vesa
[    19.962] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    20.180] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[    20.201] (EE) 
[    20.201] (EE) Backtrace:
[    20.225] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x48) [0x7f6916bb3848]
[    20.225] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x7f6916a0a000+0x1ad539) [0x7f6916bb7539]
[    20.225] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f6915b06000+0x10340) [0x7f6915b16340]
[    20.225] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f690e997000+0x125fcb) [0x7f690eabcfcb]
[    20.225] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f690e997000+0x82263) [0x7f690ea19263]
[    20.225] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f690e997000+0xfa591) [0x7f690ea91591]
[    20.225] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f690e997000+0xf2c74) [0x7f690ea89c74]
[    20.225] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f690e997000+0xf33b0) [0x7f690ea8a3b0]
[    20.225] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f690e997000+0xa3fbb) [0x7f690ea3afbb]
[    20.225] (EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f690e997000+0x9fa1b) [0x7f690ea36a1b]
[    20.225] (EE) 10: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f690e997000+0xee436) [0x7f690ea85436]
[    20.225] (EE) 11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f690e997000+0x62bdab) [0x7f690efc2dab]
[    20.225] (EE) 12: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f690e997000+0x61d0d1) [0x7f690efb40d1]
[    20.225] (EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (AddScreen+0x71) [0x7f6916a60191]
[    20.225] (EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (InitOutput+0x3c8) [0x7f6916aa1378]
[    20.225] (EE) 15: /usr/bin/X (0x7f6916a0a000+0x59bab) [0x7f6916a63bab]
[    20.225] (EE) 16: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f6914546ec5]
[    20.225] (EE) 17: /usr/bin/X (0x7f6916a0a000+0x451ee) [0x7f6916a4f1ee]
[    20.225] (EE) 
[    20.225] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x30
[    20.226] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    20.226] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[    20.226] (EE) 
[    20.226] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    20.226] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    20.226] (EE) 
[    20.226] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Thanks in advance

Craig

[image: Bios screen with rows of dots]
[image: frozen login screen without nomodeset using nouveau drivers]

Comment: i agree, dots in bios would just mean hardware problem

Answer (score 0):

Just to update in case useful to anyone else.

It turned out it was a hardware fault with the graphics card, so I tried the oven baking method described in the overclockers link and it worked!! Graphics now all A OK. 10mins at gas mark 5 did the trick

[card ready for baking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/842TD.jpg)